# Adding data to element so jQuery can use it

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for an elegant way to add data to an element on server side so that jQuery/JavaScript can use it. I also do not want to make too many calls to server so data must be there upfront.

Scenario example.
Server side (PHP), I create a list of user images. To this, I want to add name, surname, age, etc.
 
When clicking on the images, jQuery must then do something with this data.

Possibilities I've considered:
Have the data as href, then on click, get the href and return false.
Have the data as classes.

Are there any better ways?

Comment: You could simply hide the data when the page is first served up, then use jquery to toggle its visibility? No extra calls to the server are required. You should also post some code to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML specification reserves attributes beginning with `data-` for this purpose. For example:

```
<p data-name="John Doe" data-age="256">Hello World</p>
```

You can name them as you like as long as you follow the `data-*` format.

If you want structured semantic data, consider using [RDFa Lite](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) with an appropriate schema.

Comment: Thank you (and others who posted an answer). Simple things like this you miss in life. :)

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5, you have [custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

If you want valid HTML for older specs, the best option is probably to have the data embedded in `<span>` elements that are styled as `display:none` and located in a way that associates them with the image and is easy to access with jQuery (e.g. as a child element with a specific class).

Answer (score 0):

You can create `data` attributes:

```
<a href="link.html" data-content="demo">Text</a>
```

And then read them with:

```
$('a').data('content');
```

Comment: Why use attr when you can use data("content")

Comment: Yeah True :) Good point.

Answer (score 0):

if you have lots of data elements, you can keep them out of the markup by storing the data in a Javascript variable, and just use a `data-userid` or `id` attribute to store an ID reference to the user data.

For example if you have a PHP array of users you could json_encode it into a Javascript variable:

```
var users = <?php echo json_encode($users); ?>;
```

In your markup, just store the ID:

```
<img src="..." alt="..." data-userid="x" />
```

You can then lookup the data in your Javascript array. The benefit of this approach is if you need to store lots of data, it is unobtrusive on the markup.